# How to make .populate exclude null values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

Is there a way to exclude lessons.lesson_id that are equal to null? I have the following from previous answers, but it's still giving lessons.lesson_id that are null

```
module.exports.getClasses = function(id, callback){
    Class.findById(id)
    .populate(
        {path: 'lessons.lesson_id',
        model: 'Lesson', $ne: null}
    ).exec(callback)
}

var classSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    lessons: [{
        _id: false,
        lesson_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Lesson'}
    }],
});
```

I'm trying to prevent the lesson_id with null from showing up

```
{ _id: 58090,
  title: 'vcvc',
  __v: 0,
  lessons: [ { lesson_id: null }, { lesson_id: [Object] } ] }
```

Comment: Are you looking to not have any classes w/ null lessons? I'm not clear what query result you're expecting otherwise.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. If a Lesson = null, then I don't want it to be populated.

Answer (score 0):

So your ClassSchema is a touch off, I think you may find this will work better based on your requirements:

```
var classSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    lessons: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Lesson'}],
});
```